# Как импортировать класс из другого модуля?

Tags: python

Есть  класс `Connector`, который имеет следующий конструктор:

```
class Connector():
    def __init__(self, filename='config.ini', section='mysql'):
        parser = ConfigParser()
        parser.read(filename)

        self.db = {}
        if parser.has_section(section):
            items = parser.items(section)
            for item in items:
                self.db[item[0]] = item[1]
        else:
            raise Exception('{0} not found in the {1}'.format(section, filename))
```

Если я делаю

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    connector = Connector()
```

в том же модуле где он лежит, то все работает. Однако при создании объекта в другом модуле возникает ошибка:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

В чем дело ?

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Я понял, что не умею импортировать... Если ввести connector = Connector.Connector(), то все хорошо. Как избежать этого указывания имени модуля перед именем класса ?

Comment: `from Connector import Connector`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

файл с кодом класса Conector(модуль) переименуйте.

```
from MyModule import Connector
```